# WCF Service with netTcpBinding + windows Authentication hosted with IIS and using roles for authorization

Tags: wcf, iis, nettcpbinding

I am having a WCF Service which is hosted with IIS with nettcpbinding and Windows authentication, I am trying to do authorization with user name/roles. But service is allowing any user to access it.

Is this possible in first place?

Comment: Which version of IIS?? IIS6 does **not** support anything but HTTP....

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have some soft of configuration error.  IIS does not allow for hosting of WCF with the nettcp binding.  You'll need to host your WCF in a Windows Service or WAS (only in Windows Server 2008).  See *Learning WCF*, by Michele Leroux Bustamante for an excellent reference on how to do this.

Comment: I am able to host it with IIS 7, but for me the 
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="domain\someuser"/>
<deny users="*"/>
</....

Is not working, anyone is able to access the service